# How to find or create with Knex?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, knex.js

In terms of a simple user registration, how can I do a find or create by username with best performance in mind? Guessing I need to use raw queries but I'm not so sql savvy as of yet.

Or at least some kind rejection if the username already exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With mysql you probably need like 3 queries, since it doesn't support well common table expressions (maybe some really new mysql actually supports them) nor returning inserted data:

Get user, if not found insert, get user again ([Mysql fetch the row just inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797976/mysql-fetch-the-row-just-inserted)).

Something like:

```
  knex.transaction(trx => {
    trx('users').where('username', name).then(res => {
      if (res.length === 0) {
        return trx('users').insert({ username: name }).then(() => {
          return trx('users').where('username', name);
        });
      } else {
        return res;
      }
    });
  }).then(res => console.log(`User is: ${res[0]}`));
```

Comment: Yeah I was scared this was the answer. I wanted to slim it to as little queries as possible, but oh well. So, under the hood, in an ORM like Sequelize or Bookshelf, in their wrappers (e.g. findOrCreate), does it essentially boil down to this verbose type of query? Or should I use an ORM to handle these transactions better?

Comment: Yes. Under the hood ORM's doesn't have any better way to do it either. Usually its better to use some kind of ORM when developing any complicated software dealing with related data.  Otherwise you just end up writing similar abstractions by yourself. The one we are using (and developing) in vincit http://vincit.github.io/objection.js/ its built on knex and has quite a big set of extra features to make life easier when dealing with relations and fetching / inserting nested data. Hopefully we'll also add json support for mysql at some point (that feature is currently postgres only).

Comment: Instead of repeating `'username', name` repeatedly, I'd do `payload={username:name}` and then pass `payload` to everything.

Comment: I've just been looking at this and I had to add return to trx('users) like so: `return trx('users')...`

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with this for a whole day. Not sure if this solution works with all databases supported by Knex. I'm using PostgreSQL.

```
knex('users')
  .insert(
    db('users')
      .select(knex.raw('? ? ?', [
        username,
        first_name,
        last_name
      ]))
      .whereNotExists(
        knex('users').select(0).where({username})
      )
      .limit(1)
  );
```